# Fluent Validation goes in System.ArgumentNullException when i pass '\' at the end or start of the input

Tags: c#, .net, rest, fluentvalidation

I'm using Fluent Validation in my application to validate user input. I have encountered an issue where the validation fails and throws a System.ArgumentNullException when I pass a " \ " character at the end of the input string.

Here is an example of the validation rule I'm using:

```
RuleFor(cb => cb.Address)
.NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Address field is required.")
.Matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$").WithMessage("The Address field must contain only letters and numbers.");
```

When I provide an input value with " \ " at the end, such as " ferrari\ " or at start like " \ferrari ", the validation throws the mentioned exception. However, if I remove the '' character or place it anywhere else in the input, the validation works as expected.

here is the complete log error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Cannot pass null model to Validate. (Parameter 'instanceToValidate')
   at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.EnsureInstanceNotNull(Object instanceToValidate) in /Users/jskinner/code/FluentValidation/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs:line 516
   at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.ValidateAsync(ValidationContext`1 context, CancellationToken cancellation) in /Users/jskinner/code/FluentValidation/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs:line 247
   at ecommerce.Controllers.AuthController.Login(DTO_CustomerLogin customer) in D:\Lavoro\ecommerce\ecommerce\ecommerce\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 30
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======

Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7298
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/98.0.0.0
:method: POST
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check,wordpress_logged_in_743590ba59234b9fc8eaaf393199b671=admin%7C1685559922%7C2IGA4sVh57u8X2IiPvPH55IiFpWW8Bbh7A6bJeAOPCY%7C5922389646a2f0cdae23863404146ff7a36b7e4ec26b2cee87d6495403b7c9c2,tk_ai=woo%3A7xGM8dng5IbSM3DfhUjxnCMi,wp-settings-time-1=1685387348
Origin: https://localhost:7298
Referer: https://localhost:7298/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 48
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Not_A Brand";v="24", "Opera GX";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` does allow spaces also `[.....0-9space_here]`

Comment: Wonder how are you testing the validation. Do you know that `string test = " ferrari\ ";` is way different to `string test = @" ferrari\ ";`?

Comment: here is how i testing the validation, i have an API call that add a billing address to a customer, if in the address i send for example: 'my address\' the DTO that i pass to the service with the property 'my address\' is passing null to the service so is going in exception, but why adding \ in any property make is return null?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the same issue. But I suspect that the object you are passing to your `ValidateAsync` method is `null`.

Also, I'd suggest using `\s` to check for whitespace in your regex instead of literal space. Something like this : `Matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$")`

Comment: Also when i pass to my api call, an property with '\' at the end, the object is not passing the value to my service but return null, i don't know why, how i bypass this?

Comment: @Petruz21 Are you deserializing '\' from an incoming payload? Can you share the piece of code that calls your validator?

Comment: or `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$"` to ease the readability